# Why am I receiving a CSP Error in my Google Apps Script File?

Tags: angularjs, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm having an issue with my Google Apps Script file. Its essentially mirroring a Room Reservation system and up until recently it started to have some issues. I'm having a Content Security Policy issue that shows when I try to run it on FireFox.

[image: Current issue that I'm seeing.]

When I go on Chrome, I get a different error:

[image]

I have an Admin Console, that gives me the option to accept or decline Room Reservations. Currently, the only account that shows any of the Rooms is mine.

The intended look should be this, with the rooms shown below: [image]

However, what other Admins are seeing is this:

[image]

It shows no CSS, and I get either one of the errors above.

Currently, on my Admin Console Script, I have this, which is where the issues come about:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>

<html ng-app="directoryApp">

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="directoryCtrl" class="container-fluid" ng-init="getEvents(<?= user ?>)">

      <!-- Show loading screen -->
      <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Loading').getContent(); ?>
      <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('License').getContent(); ?>

      <!-- Show notifications -->
      <div id="page_top" class="notify lead" ng-if="notification">{{notification}}</div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <div ng-show="events" ng-csp>
                  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AC-Navigation').getContent(); ?>
                </div>

                <div ng-show="events.length && !editing && !settings">

                  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AC-List').getContent(); ?>

                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" ng-show="editing">
                  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AC-Single').getContent(); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="settings">
                  <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AC-Settings').getContent(); ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>

    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AC-JavaScript').getContent(); ?>
```

I tried to look at some Angular Documentation, that spoke about using `ng-csp`, which didn't work.

There is no issue with the actual reservation system itself, its just that I cannot see the rest of the code on the Admin Console, and as a result I cannot accept/deny room requests on my app.

I tried to also use a `meta` that allows for everything through `Content-Security-Policy`.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: ``src="https://ajax...."``

Comment: Its still giving me the CSP Error..

Comment: Meta tags are ignored  for security purposes.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I removed the Meta tags and the issue still remains. My script now has `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>`